# Cannot get the right output for swapping in list (python)

Tags: python

```
def largestPermutation(k, arr):
    for i in range(k):
        arr[i],arr[arr.index(max(arr[i:]))]=arr[arr.index(max(arr[i:]))],arr[i] 
    return arr

a =[4,2,3,5,1]
print(largestPermutation(1,a))
```

This is my code to return the largest permutation in a list with k swaps. I tried the Pen and paper method and got the code as follows but, the answer returns the same array I passed.

This is a HackerRank problem (Link : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/largest-permutation/problem)

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `i` in the loop, not `k`?

Comment: Sorry, I tried that but the answer still returns the input array

Comment: Try `arr[arr.index(max(arr[i:]))],arr[i] = arr[i],arr[arr.index(max(arr[i:]))]`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in the destination of the assignment, `arr[arr.index(max(arr[i:])]` is calculated *after* `arr[i]` has been assigned. So the maximum element has already been moved into the front position, so this will always return the index that you're swapping into and it gets its original value back.

Assign the index of the max element to a variable before doing the swap.

```
def largestPermutation(k, arr):
    for i in range(k):
        max_index = arr.index(max(arr[i:]))
        arr[i],arr[max_index]=arr[max_index],arr[i] 
    return arr

a =[4,2,3,5,1]
print(largestPermutation(1,a))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should assign it first as a variable:

```
def largestPermutation(k, arr):
    for i in range(k):
        x = arr.index(max(arr[i:]))
        arr[i], arr[x] = arr[x], arr[i] 
    return arr

a =[4, 2, 3, 5, 1]
print(largestPermutation(1, a))
```

Output:

```
[5, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```